# Find a string in registry and export that key name

Tags: powershell

I wish to search in a particular key of the registry, which contains about 20 subkeys, for part of a known string. I don't need to be able to search elsewhere in the registry. When it's found I need to be able export that key, with full path, to a variable.

Comment: Nice and easily done mate. Where do you seem to be having problems? I can't see your broken code to assist in the repair and explanation.

Comment: I dont have it as yet, its beyond my abilities. I was intending starting it tomorrow  I know how to check if a particular key and a value exists, but i need to search for whether a particular string of text appears as part of a value in a range of keys/subkeys.

Comment: No worries, come back after you have tested your script and let us know where it fails.

Comment: Hi jayjay80, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what you've already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Scripts for this use case exist. Just search the web and the MS PowerShellGallery.com for them. Mess, with them and come back, if you have issues with what you try and fail with.

```
Get-Command -Name '*registry*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                                          Version Source
----------- ----                                          ------- ------
...
Function    Get-RemoteRegistryChildItem                   1.3.6   PowerShellCookbook
Function    Get-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty                 1.3.6   PowerShellCookbook
Function    Grant-RegistryAccessFullControl               1.3.6   PowerShellCookbook
Function    Search-Registry                               1.3.6   PowerShellCookbook
Function    Set-RemoteRegistryKeyProperty                 1.3.6   PowerShellCookbook
...

Find-Module -Name '*registry*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name                      Repository Description
------- ----                      ---------- -----------
...
0.0.2   PoshRegistry              PSGallery  This module contains functions to create, modify or delete registry subkeys and values on local or remote c...
...
1.0.0.1 xRegistryAccess           PSGallery  Manage registry permissions
...
```